# Outstanding invoices using data.table's non-equi self join

Tags: r, data.table

I want to know if it is possible to calculate the number of the outstanding invoices prior to the issue date of a new invoice using a data.table's non-equi self join.

Here is the demo data:

```
library(data.table)
demo <- data.table(
ClientId = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7), 
IssueDate =  as.Date(c("2016-12-09", "2015-10-23", "2015-12-01", "2016-09-08", "2016-10-10", "2014-10-02", "2015-10-26", "2016-10-03", "2016-12-27",
"2017-03-29", "2017-03-29", "2017-05-22")), 
ClearingDate = as.Date(c("2017-07-06", "2015-10-26", "2015-12-02", "2016-09-09", "2016-11-15", "2014-11-18", "2015-12-14", "2017-01-13", "2017-01-13",
"2017-06-05", "2017-04-12", "2017-06-19")),
Amount = c(517, 45, 79, 1891, 603, 15, 1706, 975, 53, 78, 92, 158))
```

And here it is one example to calculate the number of total paid invoices and the sum of the amount of total paid invoices.

```
demo[demo, .(num_total_paid_invoices = .N,
sum_total_paid_invoices = sum(Amount)),
on = .(ClientId,
ClearingDate < IssueDate),
by = .EACHI]


   ClientId ClearingDate num_total_paid_invoices sum_total_paid_invoices
 1:        1   2016-12-09                       0                      NA
 2:        2   2015-10-23                       0                      NA
 3:        2   2015-12-01                       1                      45
 4:        2   2016-09-08                       2                     124
 5:        3   2016-10-10                       0                      NA
 6:        4   2014-10-02                       0                      NA
 7:        4   2015-10-26                       1                      15
 8:        4   2016-10-03                       2                    1721
 9:        4   2016-12-27                       2                    1721
10:        5   2017-03-29                       0                      NA
11:        6   2017-03-29                       0                      NA
12:        7   2017-05-22                       0                      NA
```

I thought that this would work, but didn't.

```
demo[demo, .(
  num_total_outstanding_invoices = .N,
  sum_total_outstanding_invoices = sum(Amount)
),
on = .(ClientId,
       IssueDate < IssueDate,
       ClearingDate > IssueDate
),
by = .EACHI]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please test your code before posting. Currently, it gives missing dates where you broke the string over two lines. Also, could you show the desired output? Your join looks right to me.

Comment: Thanks. The code is edited now.

Comment: For some reason I don't know, that code don't work with the real data I'm workin on. But it works with that demo data...

Comment: If I correctly understood your question, it seems to me your code works with your sample data.  `demo[, IssueDate - shift(ClearingDate), by = ClientId]` shows that only row 9 has been issued before the earlier invoices were settled.  This is also the result of your code. Perhaps, you could add `nomatch = 0L` to return only the affected row.

Comment: Hi, Uwe. I tried your proposal and it seems it works now with the real data. Thank you very much! :D